# jQuery event.Preventdefault(); is not doing anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have some scripts on my site that send replies to a server and reload the page using ajax. sometimes though, it reloads the page for no reason.

so I added this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("form").submit(function(){
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
            )
    </script>
```

but it is still reloading the page when i hit sumbit.
why.

Comment: Where are you placing this script tag? You might need to use domready or place the script tag after the form tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You simply forgot to bring in the event argument into the handler:

```
$("form").submit(function( event ) {
```

Also: check the error console, in your example code you are missing an ending bracket **}**);

As a side note: make sure you are selecting the `form` element after it has been loaded, to be safe use `domReady`:

```
$(function() {
    $("form").submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: In preference to the `ready` event, simply put the scripts at the end of the document, just prior to the closing `</body>` tag. More: [YUI Best Practices](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom) | [Google Closure Engineers on when DOM is ready](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/closure-library-discuss/G-7Ltdavy0E/RjllWWJTXAcJ)

Answer (score 1):

`event` as a global (`window.event`) is non-standard. jQuery normalizes this for you, so just pass in `event` as an argument:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  // Make sure you wait until the document is ready
    $("form").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Also, returning `false` calls `event.preventDefault()` as well as `event.stopPropagation()`. You only want the first to happen, so be explicit.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("form").submit(function(event){})
```

Answer (score 0):

In a comment on another answer, you've said:

> it still reloads the page

That suggests that you have this code *above* the form you want it to act on in the HTML. Move the script below the form (usually just before the closing `</body>` tag is best), or use jQuery's `ready` event.

Also note that if you're using `return false`, you don't need `event.preventDefault`, because `return false` from a jQuery event handler does `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropagation()`, so:

```
<form ...>
<!-- ... -->
</form>
<!-- ... -->
<script>
$("form").submit(function(){
    return false;
});
</script>
</body>
```

Or alternately, this anywhere on the page, using the shortcut for [`ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready):

```
$(function() {
    $("form").submit(function(){
        return false;
    });
});
```